# Creating articles on Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I don't know if it has been asked before...

Anyways, I want to create a site for an online magazine in which editors can write and post articles, e.g. BBC, CNN, The Guardian, etc. Is that possible with Joomla? Or do I need a plugin for that. I really don't want wordpress as it is for blogging.

I'm very new with Joomla...

Also if there are alternatives to Joomla for writing articles then let me know as well, please.

Many Thanks

Comment: Define "article". What features are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Shouldn't you ask this at [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Pekka; Any article, i.e. news articles, fashion articles, etc... like on BBC, CNN, etc websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has a workflow so that you can create an article but needs to be approved by Editor etc. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean, do you know how to do that or can you give me a reference where I can learn how to do it, please?

Comment: @Shaoz:  Wordpress has the same functionality and is often used for News sites.  Not many people use Joomla! anymore, so good luck with your site!

Comment: @Jazzerus: But I don't want to do blogs, which is what Wordpress is for, and my client wants a proper site like BBC and CNN (I keep mentionning those sites...), and other news sites... If you know what I'm talking about of course...

Comment: @Shaoz: Wordpress isn't just for blogs. See ma.tt's post for an example of a news site that's built on WP: http://ma.tt/2007/10/best-wp-newspaper-site/